# Getting a permanent access token for facebook application with credentials

Tags: facebook, desktop-application

Can i get a permanent access token for my facebook application , using user's credentials (email, password). 
As i have seen in many application like yahoo messenger ,windows live , nimbuzz for mobile 
and other, they just ask for username and password ,
and they got added in my apps,
So pls tell me , how can i get it done....
i want to create a desktop application in which i will take users credentials and 
in my desktop application ,
i will take users action to get it done on his wall....
Pls help

Comment: I believe asking for a user's Facebook credentials is against policy.  Check with your attorney before proceeding any further with this app.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask for the offline_access extended permission, which provides you with an access token that is valid until the user either revokes your app or changes his/her password.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Comment: thanx for reply,
but i was asking that 
if i take users credentials on my desktop application (in java)
can i get access token for that user only by credentials while not redirecting .....

Comment: offline_access is deprecated.

Comment: @Vijay How would you achieve this?

Comment: this is what i want to achieve before but as i get to know in comments that offline_access is deprecated. so it is not possible directly. there may be other solutions to it available.